# 403 Forbidden even I granted access

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I created a project using spring security.

In `configure(HttpSecurity http)` I set access to `"/home"` just for USER, but after I login, it shows:

> 403 Forbidden

I created an `Entity class named User implementing UserDetails` and in `getAuthorities()` I just retrun `Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));`

For http object, I tried using directly `.hasRole('USER')` method instead of `.access("hasRole('USER')")`, the problem is the same.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/home")
          .access("hasRole('USER')")
          .antMatchers("/","/**").access("permitAll")
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Authority and not Role.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/home").hasAuthority("USER")
      .antMatchers("/","/**").access("permitAll")
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
}
```